# Inject a theme setting form into a block

Tags: theming, blocks

Is there a way to inject the theme settings form into a block so it could fix to the left-hand side of the page when admin logins?

The url that would be injected into the block would be

```
admin/appearance/settings/<theme_name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom block: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-blocks/create-a-custom-block

In the build() method, you can return the form:

```
public function build() {
  return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\system\Form\ThemeSettingsForm');
}
```